# Django User model Groups and permissions error abstracteduser

Tags: django, authentication

I'm busy creating a User model in Django that can Authenticate users for login, I'm using abstracteduser to create this model but I am constantly getting this error when making the migrations:

```
ERRORS:
api.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor 'Group.user_set' for 'api.User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'auth.User.groups'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'api.User.groups' or 'auth.User.groups'.

api.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor 'Permission.user_set' for 'api.User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'auth.User.user_permissions'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'api.User.user_permissions' or 'auth.User.user_permissions'.

auth.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor 'Group.user_set' for 'auth.User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'api.User.groups'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'auth.User.groups' or 'api.User.groups'.

auth.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor 'Permission.user_set' for 'auth.User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'api.User.user_permissions'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'auth.User.user_permissions' or 'api.User.user_permissions'.
```

The code I've implemented for it:

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    #User first name eg. Piet
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length= 60, validators=[MinLengthValidator(3)],      verbose_name= "First name", null= False, blank= False)
    # User surname
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length= 60, validators=[MinLengthValidator(3)], verbose_name= "Surname", null= False, blank= False)
    #user type
    user_type = models.ForeignKey(UserPlans, on_delete= models.PROTECT, related_name='userType')
    #user email
    user_email = models.EmailField()
    # total requests made by the user
    request_count = models.IntegerField(default= 0 , verbose_name="totalRequests", validators = [MinValueValidator(0, message="Age cannot be negative")], null= False, blank= False)
    # Last request that was made by the user  
    last_request = models.DateField( auto_now_add= True,  null= False, blank= False,   verbose_name= "Last request date", editable= False)
    # User current APS
    user_APS = models.IntegerField(null= False, default = 0 , blank= False, verbose_name="APS Score", validators= [
        MinValueValidator(0, message="APS can not be calculated as negative"),
        MaxValueValidator(44, message="APS score can not be higher than 44")
    ])
    #When last the users APS was calculated
    last_updated_APS = models.DateField(null= True, blank= True, verbose_name="APS updated")
    #users selected plan

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Users"
        ordering = ['id']

    def getUserInformation(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name} {self.user_type}"
    
    def __str__ (self):
        return self.getUserInformation()
```

Is there anything that I'm missing here?
TIA